# SQL. как разделить значения одного столбца на значения другого в sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

SQL. как разделить значения одного столбца на значения другого в sql, чтобы получить новое расчетное значение?

Comment: Не поверите, знаком деления, обычно изображаемом как наклонная черта. `столбец1 / столбец2`

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.dividend
       ,t.divisor
       ,CAST(t.dividend as FLOAT) / CAST(t.divisor as FLOAT) as result
from your_table t
```

Comment: А привидение к типу FLOAT одного из значений не нужно делать, если они оба INT ?

Comment: @iluxa1810, согласен. Подправил.